# Should I answer to mongoose questions when they are actually about mongodb?

Tags: discussion

I am willing to answer questions about mongodb. I am not a mongoose user. When you follow the mongodb tag, you'll see that many, many mongodb questions are also tagged mongoose and in fact they ask for solutions in mongoose. On the other hand, the issue is usually about mongodb only, something that I could answer ([and I've done so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31852925/find-the-documents-in-mongoose-whose-array-fields-exactly-match/31853603#31853603)), because mongoose is just the client library the OP has to use to send the commands to mongodb.
What should be my behaviour?

- Ignore the fact that the OP mentioned mongoose and answer. In this case, my answer would help, but tecnically I've not really answered the question, since it asked for a solution in mongoose. Further, I'll have mongoose in my top tags, which feels weird
- Point out that the question should be about mongodb only, since the mongoose part is standard/easy/you can find it everywhere. Sounds like the best thing to do, but could unnecessarily upset the OP.
- Stay away, leave those question to someone who knows mongoose and can fully answer. That's sad, because I'm cut out of a lot of mongodb questions I could have answered.

Of course, my question applies only to such cases when the mongoose part doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I will be answering in general terms, as I would judge any tag pairing. This is not specific to the communities in [mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb) or [mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoose).

> Of course, my question applies only to such cases when the mongoose part doesn't really matter.

What you're describing sounds mainly like a case of the OP including superfluous tags, or possibly even misunderstanding the relationship or difference between the client library and the backend service. This sort of misunderstanding is very common.

> Stay away, leave those question to someone who knows mongoose and can fully answer. That's sad, because I'm cut out of a lot of mongodb questions I could have answered.

Absolutely not. If you can supply an answer that will solve the question, regardless of whether it includes code for all the question's tags, you should  answer it with confidence.

> Point out that the question should be about mongodb only, since the mongoose part is standard/easy/you can find it everywhere. Sounds like the best thing to do, but could unnecessarily upset the OP.

As you said, you're primarily concerned with those questions where [mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoose) is not relevant.  If it is truly irrelevant, feel free to suggest an edit which removes the [mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongoose) tag; don't bother pointing out in comments that the tag isn't needed -- that is why posts are editable by the community.  You need not worry about upsetting the OP because your edit suggestion is meant to benefit all future readers of the question & answers and contribute to the overall quality of indexing on the site.

> Ignore the fact that the OP mentioned mongoose and answer. In this case, my  answer would help, but tecnically I've not really answered the question, since it asked for a solution in mongoose.

This is a bit different, in that it implies the OP intentionally asked for a mongoose solution. Use some judgement here, because it is still valuable to future readers if you provide an answer in the form of:

> *Here is a plain mongodb solution without mongoose...*

Comment: Thanks. Usually it is not just a superflous/wrong tag: the OP intentionally asks for a mongoose solution. If you check the question i linked, mongoose is mentioned in the title, in the body, in the snippets. My answer, on the other hand, is about mongodb and it was accepted anyhow. Seems like mogoose is now so popular that so many people ask directly for a solution with that, even if they have an issue which is purely mongodb. I guess that your last piece of advise is what I should take

Comment: @MarioTrucco I see it all the time - Rails when only Ruby is necessary, jQuery when it's mostly plain JavaScript, PHPMyAdmin when the question is about MySQL...  Any solution you can provide that actually solves the problem should be welcomed by the community.